# Why is my mac system's path directory so long?

Tags: macos, terminal

I just ran the command

```
echo $PATH
```

The output was:

```
/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Why is it so long? Shouldn't it look more like 
`/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite normal to have a `PATH` variable that is long. Yours contain some duplicate entries but this is not a real problem.

If you execute a command without specifing a path the shell searches in each path specified in the PATH variable to find it. In your example it search in `/opt/anaconda3/condabin` and after that in  `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` and so on.

It is normal to have multiple places for executables and thus multiple entries in the `PATH` variable separated with colon. Often third party software like Anaconda in your example adds it own folder to the PATH variable. 
Have a look at `/etc/paths`, `/etc/paths.d` and your shell profile where those path might be added.

And from a security standpoint your PATHS could be risky if /opt/anaconda3/condabin or /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin is writeable by the user/others as anybody can place malicious executable there masking the system supplied ones in /bin or /usr/bin.
If not absolutely neccessary third party pathes should be added to the end as they normally shouldn't replace existing binaries.